# ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn

Пытаюсь создать код на питоне, чтобы он со страницы ria.ru/economy/ парсил заголовки статей начиная с 2015 года заканчивая нашим днём, затем заголовки лемматизировал и применял TF-IDF. Код выглядит вот так:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd

# Список для хранения заголовков статей
headlines = []

# Функция для лемматизации текста
def lemmatize_text(text):
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    return ' '.join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(text)])

# Загрузка страницы
url = "https://ria.ru/economy/"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# Поиск заголовков статей
articles = soup.find_all(class_="list-item")
for article in articles:
    # Проверка года публикации статьи
    year = article.find(class_="list-itemdate")
    if year and int(year.text) >= 2015:
        # Добавление заголовка в список
        headline = article.find(class_="list-itemtitle")
        if headline:
            headlines.append(headline.text)

# Сохранение заголовков в CSV файле
with open("headlines.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Headline"])
    writer.writerows(headlines)

# Лемматизация заголовков
lemmatized_headlines = [lemmatize_text(headline) for headline in headlines]

# Применение метода TF-IDF к словам в заголовках
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(lemmatized_headlines)
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

# Создание DataFrame с TF-IDF значениями
tfidf_data = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_matrix.toarray(), columns=feature_names)

# Вывод первых 5 строк DataFrame
print(tfidf_data.head())
```

Однако при компиляции выдаёт следующее:

```
File "C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/ytsan.py", line 44, in <module>
    tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(lemmatized_headlines)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 2139, in fit_transform
    X = super().fit_transform(raw_documents)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 1152, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1389, in fit_transform
    vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1295, in _count_vocab
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words
```

Пытался добавить разные параметры к TfidfVectorizer, ибо очевидно он ругается на него, однако ничего не помогает - ошибка остаётся такой же, не нравятся ему стоп-слова. Помогите пожалуйста, кто чем сможет.